# Ever-decreasing loss in neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss

My neural network receives a `(1000, 1000, 5)` shape array which undergoes convolution in one branch (5 stacked raster images) and a `(12)` shape array (just 12 numbers) which go through a couple of dense layers in a second branch.

The outputs are concatenated into a `(31, 31, 65)` shape tensor which then goes deconvolution into a final `(1000, 1000)` shape array.

#### My Issue:

I made my own simple loss function (mean error), because the output represents temperature in an area.
My issue is currently that my loss goes down significantly over 200 epochs (both `loss` and `val_loss`, from a small decimal to about -3) and the accuracy hovers around 0.002 the entire time .
I have changed the learning rate as low as `1e-5`. I have given more samples to the training set (there aren't many samples to begin with unfortunately), increased (for fear of overfitting) and decreased (for lack of data) the batch size. All the input data is normalized to 0:1, which makes losses of anything beyond `-1` unreasonable.

I am not sure whether I should use a different optimizer for this task, or different activation, or just remove a layer or two. But mostly I'd love to understand what is happening to make the model so unreliable.
I really tried to refrain from having to post the entire thing on here but I am officially out of ideas.

### MLP Branch

```py
    dim = 12
    inputs = Input(shape = (dim, ))

    x = inputs
    x = Dense(dim * 4, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dense(dim * 16, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dense(961, activation = 'relu')(x)  # 961 nodes
    x = Reshape((31, 31, 1))(x)  # (31, 31, 1) array

    model1 = Model(inputs, x)
```

### Convolutional Branch

```py
    inputShape = (1000, 1000, 5)
    chanDim = -1
    inputs = Input(shape = inputShape)

    x = inputs

    # layer 1: conv, f = 8, pool = 2
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis = chanDim)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(x)

    # layer 2: conv, f = 16, pool = 2
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis = chanDim)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(x)

    # layer 3: conv, f = 32, pool = 2
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis = chanDim)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(x)

    # layer 4: conv = 64, pool = 4
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis = chanDim)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (4, 4))(x)

    model2 = Model(inputs, x)
```

### Deconvolution

```py
    combinedInput = Concatenate()([model1.output, model2.output])
    x = combinedInput  # (31, 31, 65)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(43, (3, 3), strides = (4, 4), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)  # (124, 124, 43)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(22, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)  # (248, 248, 22)
    x = Lambda(lambda y: spatial_2d_padding(y))(x)  # (250, 250, 22)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(10, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)  # (500, 500, 10)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same', activation = 'linear')(x)  # (1000, 1000, 1)
    x = Lambda(lambda y: squeeze(y, axis = 3))(x)  # (1000, 1000)
```

### Compiling

```py
    def custom_loss(y_actual, y_predicted):
        custom_loss_value = mean(y_actual - y_predicted)
        return custom_loss_value

    model = Model(inputs = [mlp.input, cnn.input], outputs = x)
    model.compile(loss = custom_loss, optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.000001), metrics = ['mae'])
    # train with epochs = 200, batch_size = 12
```

### The Issue

As I explained above, my loss never stabilizes and the accuracy hovers roughly around the same number over the epochs.

I'd love to know possible reasons and possible solutions.
[image: Epoch Loss]

#### Edits:

Since writing this question I have attempted:

- [Transfering layers](https://divamgupta.com/image-segmentation/2019/06/06/deep-learning-semantic-segmentation-keras.html) from the convolution branch to the deconvolution branch.
- Adding `BatchNormalization()` after every `Conv2DTranspose()` layer.

Comment: Have you tried mean(abs(y_actual - y_predicted)), ie. MAE or mean((y_actual - y_predicted)**2), ie MSE? As optimizers try to minimize the error, when your error doesn't have an actual limit it will just keep decreasing. Obviously this is an issue as an error of 8e-3 is just as bad as -8e-3!

Comment: MSE was the first one I tried. The numbers are much smaller but the trend is the same - the loss doesn't stabilize.

Comment: Does it still go negative? MSE by definition is always positive (or 0).